# How do I make a MySQL query that searches for terms both forwards and backwards?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following search terms (from three example words) that a user may enter:

```
"goofy plastic toy"
"goofy toy plastic"
"plastic goofy toy"
"plastic toy goofy"
"toy goofy plastic"
"toy plastic goofy"
```

How so I write a proper `SELECT` statement that can look at all statements without having to hardcode `OR`?

So just:

```
SELECT a
FROM b
WHERE c = '<search statements in all possible ways separated by spaces here>';
```

The amount of words a user enters can be infinite. It could be two, it could be ten, who knows.

I am trying to search 100,000 product titles and their descriptions and pull out which records contain **all** words in **any order**.

Comment: Here is a list of MySQL functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html I would try to make use of the REVERSE() function.

Comment: You can use regular expressions in WHERE statements if you don't care about performance.

Comment: Will it always be two words? You'll need to make use of the `INSTR()` function to find spaces and then perhaps `REPLACE()` to swap the positions of the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return rows that contain those two words in any order (even if they also contain other words) then you may want to use a [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) index like this:

```
SELECT a
FROM b
WHERE MATCH (c) AGAINST ('+goofy +plastic' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Works great against a single column, but when I add two columns to the search (`title`, `description`) I always being back 0 results. How can I get the results for the combination of two or more columns? So a find of "goofy" in the `title` column and "toy" in the `description` column would count as a result?

Comment: You'll need to add a separate `FULLTEXT` index for each combination of columns you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

If youd don't care about performace you can use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). If you do, you should really consider restrcucturing your database schema. Relational databases are made to work with atomic data, not data sets. The simplest update would be to make the column ENUM or SET depending on what is more suitable for your case.